# How would I dynamically resize 4 images in one div based on the height of another div?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have a grid with one div taking up around 30% and the other 70%. In the 30% div, I have 4 images stacked vertically. In the 70% div I have content. How could I dynamically resize and crop the 4 images equally so they equal the height of the 70% content div. I know I could resize the images manually, but I'd like them to auto-adjust if content is added or removed. Also, the design is responsive. Here is a jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/fETtm/

Here is my HTML:

```
<section>
    <div id="inner-content" class="wrap">
        <aside class="fourcol first">
            <img src="https://www.slooh.com/images/signup/m42_png_sm.png">
            <img src="https://www.slooh.com/images/signup/m42_png_sm.png">
            <img src="https://www.slooh.com/images/signup/m42_png_sm.png">
            <img src="https://www.slooh.com/images/signup/m42_png_sm.png">
        </aside>

        <article class="eightcol">
            <h3>H3 Title</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        </article>
    </div>
</section>
```

Thank you for any help.

Comment: I'm not sure that you really want to do this.  Why does the left side need to be the same height as the right side?  It's generally considered best practices to decouple styling from content, because content is generally updated more frequently than styles.

Comment: You lack `alt` attribute on img so I don't know if you intend to have them as background/presentation image or as image that conveys information? If it's the former, do you need them as HTML element (in order to change them in your CMS for example) or could they be real CSS background?

Comment: Understood. But a client wants the images to equal the height of the content. I can't think of an easy way to do it without some fancy JS. Do you agree?

Comment: Purely supplemental images without a great deal of context to the content.

Comment: After putting this on paper, so to speak, I've concluded it's a silly request on behalf of the client. I'm revoking this question... thanks for those who took the few minutes to help me.

Comment: Hey, I threw [this little jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/johntobinme/rRjAq/) together using `absolute` positioning and zero `top` and `bottom` positions to auto-adjust the `aside` area. It was the first thing that came to mind for a scenario  like this. I'm just leaving so I can't go into detail, but it might be of some use to you to take a look at. (just as I'm finished typing this, I realise you're closing the question, but I'm going to post it anyway for the hell of it)

Answer (score 0):

`overflow: hidden` will cut anything outside the element it is applied (here `.wrap` your container).

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/fETtm/1/

By removing your images from the flow (`position: absolute`), only the right column is still in the flow and will define the size of its container. Now any bit of image that is outside this box won't be displayed.
As the left column was removed from the flow, your text now occupies the whole width of its container so it needs `padding-left` (same value as the width of your images).

**HTML:** same as yours

**CSS:**

```
.wrap {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    outline: 1px dashed purple;
    max-width: 1140px;
    width: 96%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.fourcol {
    width: 31.491712705%;
    position: absolute;

}

.eightcol {
    width: 65.74585634900001%;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 2.762430939%;
    padding-left: 31.491712705%;
}

.first {
    margin-left: 0;
}
```